# When are value types stored in stack(C#)?

Tags: c#

When I read next book of chapter "Value and reference types" then a question comes to my mind: "When are value types stored in stack"? Cause programmer cannot initialise any value type out of class. Cause when we initialise some variable of value type in class then variable is stored in heap.

My question is: when are value types stored in stack?

Comment: You should read the chapter again. I'm sure it is explained thoroughly in there somewhere.

Comment: All you will need to know is in this question. Some very good answers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487289/memory-allocation-stack-vs-heap

Comment: possible duplicate of [Arrays, heap and stack and value types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113819/arrays-heap-and-stack-and-value-types)

Comment: As a side-note, I've seen a lot of books *get this wrong*. I've also seen a lot of books get *describing the difference between value-types and reference-types wrong*. So it is entirely possible that the fault here is not you, but the book. I was actually technical editor on a book that made some mistakes here; I pointed out the errors repeatedly, and they weren't rectified - so I had to ask for my name to be removed from the book (I'm not there just to rubber-stamp it!)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, firstly it is very rare that you would need to know, but basically, value-types are stored *where-ever they are owned*.

They are stored *on the stack* when they are part of the execution flow of a thread, which can mean:

- in a "local" (a method variable) - excluding some cases (below)
- as a floating value in part of a method, i.e. the return value from one method that is about to be passed as a value to another method - no "local" is involved, but the value is still on the stack

  - value-type parameters that are passed by-value (i.e. without `ref` or `out`) are simply a special-case of this
- in an instance "field" (a type variable) on another value-type that is itself on the stack (for the above reasons)

They are stored *on the heap* (as part of an object) when:

- in an instance "field" on a class
- in an instance "field" on a value-type that is itself on the heap
- in a static "field"
- in an array
- in a "local" (a method variable) that is part of an iterator block, an async method, or which is a "captured" variable in a lambda or anonymous method (all of which cause the local to be hoisted onto a field on a class that is generated by the compiler)
- when "boxed" - i.e. cast into a reference-type (`object`, `dynamic`, `Enum`, `ValueType` (yes: `ValueType` is a reference-type; fun, eh?), `ISomeInterface`, etc)

Comment: To make it clear, I would add the case of the parameters... But perhaps it's a can of worms... A non-ref non-out value-type parameter?

Comment: @xanatos added as a sub-item under "floating value"

Comment: For all of your examples where you say that they're on the stack, they may in fact be in a CPU register, instead, mayn't they?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I am limiting my answer here to the IL / CLI level. What the JIT does is entirely up to the JIT. Heck, if you wanted to, I suspect you could write a stackless JIT (like stackless python)

Comment: The only way I can get discussions of heap and stack storage to make sense is if we're talking about what's actually happening at runtime, and has to be after JITting has occurred. At the IL level, the only stack that's "in scope" is the evaluation stack, and that's not where local variables are stored.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever conceptually, I would say that they are all one and the same: [incoming parameters][locals][evaluation stack]

Comment: Do I understand correctly if value type is initialized in class then it is not necessary that value type of class will be dtiredh in heap?

Comment: @StepUp a value type is always *initialized* in a **method**. What matters is *what we do next* - for example, is the value assigned to a a field? and if so: of what *type*? I cannot parse "it is not necessary that value type of class will be dtiredh in heap?", so I can't answer that - can you clarify?

Comment: sorry for my mistake. Do I understand correctly if value type is initialized ina method of a class then it is not necessary that value type of class will be stored in heap?

Comment: @StepUp if you only make use of the value in the method, then in most cases there would be no reason for it to go anywhere near the heap, indeed. The list of things that would cause it to go onto the heap are shown in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

> My question is: when are value types stored in stack?

From [The Truth About Value Types](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types.aspx):

> [I]in the Microsoft implementation of C# on the desktop CLR, value types are stored on the stack when the value is a local variable or temporary that is not a closed-over local variable of a lambda or anonymous method, and the method body is not an iterator block, and the jitter chooses to not enregister the value

Comment: Of course, that quote predates `async` - they're almost identical to iterator blocks in this regard.

Comment: Ok. But is this variable initialized in class?

Answer (score 0):

To be precise, the stack and the heap are (or should be) [irrelevant in managed environments](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx).

In practice, local variables value types (*structs* in C#) *tend* to be allocated on the stack. However, there are cases when they are allocated [on the heap instead](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types.aspx).

One such case is when they are **boxed**. Boxing means using an `Int32` as an `Object`, for example by passing it to a method that takes an `object` parameter. One reason for this is polymorphism: Structs don't carry a vTable pointer and thus cannot do dynamic virtual method resolution (for such methods as `ToString()`, for example) - but they are sealed, so they can do the resolution statically. On the other hand, if a struct is forced to be stored in an `object` reference, it needs to be transformed to a heap-allocated vTable-enabled object.

A value type may also be allocated in the heap when it's **part of a heap-allocated object** - for example, when it's a data member (field) of a class.

Answer (score 0):

Another source of confusion appears to be that you assume reference and value types are 2 types of classes, that is not true

keyword `class` -> Reference type
keyword `struct`-> Value type

Comment: at the IL level, value-types are still classes

Comment: @MarcGravell I am guessing he is talking about the keywords, i will amend as such.

Comment: I know all objects are child of System.Object. However, I mean where I can I initialize value type out if class to store it in  stack.

Answer (score 0):

The first web search hit on your question gives you Eric Lippert's [The Truth About Value Types](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types.aspx), which starts with the most important part: it is almost always irrelevant. So, why do you want to know? Will you program differently?

Anyway:

> The truth is: the choice of allocation mechanism has to do only with the known required lifetime of the storage.