# c#: What happens in a variable in memory?

Tags: c#, variables, allocation

If I have this variable:

```
string name;
```

will it be allocated a location in the memory?  Or it will only get allocated memory when I initialize it to a specific value? I.e.,

```
string name = "Jack";
```

For example, consider the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    Run();
}

private void Run() {
    int age = 20;
}
```

What will happen to the `age` value in the memory? Will it be removed from memory in each execution of the Run method? Or will it stay in the memory after the code is executed and removed after the program that uses it close?

Comment: related question [Memory Allocation stack vs. heap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487289/memory-allocation-stack-vs-heap)

Comment: Side note: A really aggressive optimizer might notice your code has no visible effects and remove everything.  ....I really need to write that extension/analyzer for VS/Roslyn, I miss it from Eclipse - there's nothing quite like watching half the stuff you've written disappear, keeps you very honest about what you're using.

Comment: Ah yes, good ol' C++ optimizing compilers.. you've got classes, function calls and loops in the code? naah, you must have imagined that

Comment: Why did you select Babak's answer as the correct one? Almost everything he said was wrong, partly wrong, or confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> string name;

If this is your only statement, the compiler will probably optimize and remove it. Without optimizations, this will be a reference to null.

> string name = "Jack";

This will create a memory allocation in the heap to store the string itself. It will also generate a pointer in your stack with the address of the allocated heap memory. Upon exiting the method and stack popped, the allocated memory in the heap will no longer have a reference and can be flagged for garbage collection.

Your 20 iterations will generate 20 stack allocations, each of which would have the value 20 in the stack with nothing generated in the heap. Upon exiting the method, the stack would be popped and the data lost.

Comment: "uninitialized (garbage) memory location" - No, it'll be a reference to `null` initially.

Comment: "generate a pointer in your stack" - No, this technically doesn't happen. It'll generate a "reference", but not a "pointer". It could be that the implementation of the run-time uses pointers, but that's not in the spec.

Comment: "will generate 20 stack allocations" - not always. It'll probably be on the stack, but it can be elsewhere.

Comment: > "in the Microsoft implementation of C# on the desktop CLR, value types are stored on the stack when the value is a local variable or temporary that is not a closed-over local variable of a lambda or anonymous method, and the method body is not an iterator block, and the jitter chooses to not enregister the value."

Comment: "create a memory allocation in the heap to store the string itself" - also no. Because this string exists at compile time the string will be created in the intern pool and is not allocated on the heap.

Answer (score 1):

For any .NET value type variable like `int`, `bool`, `double`, etc.; the memory allocation happens as soon as you declare it and when you assign value to it, the value is just updated in memory.

For reference types including `string`, on the other hand, only an address is assigned in memory which creates a reference to the actual memory location where the current value is stored (similar to pointers in C/C++).

So, in your example, `age` will be created in memory as soon as the `int age` is run and then it's value will be set to `20` when the `age = 20` gets executed.

It'll be assigned a new memory location each time the `Run()` method is executed.

Comment: "For any .NET value type variable like int, bool, double, etc.; the memory allocation happens as soon as you declare it" - Not entirely true - closures over value types, for example, don't work this way. In fact, it's like this: "in the Microsoft implementation of C# on the desktop CLR, value types are stored on the stack when the value is a local variable or temporary that is not a closed-over local variable of a lambda or anonymous method, and the method body is not an iterator block, and the jitter chooses to not enregister the value."

Comment: @Enigmativity And don't forget boxing.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this code:

```
void Main()
{
    string name;
}
```

Then, when compiled (in LINQPad) with compiler optimisation you get the following IL:

```
IL_0000:  ret
```

And without optimisation:

```
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ret
```

There is no memory allocated for this declaration - just a NOP operation as a placeholder in the IL for the unoptimised code.

When your program is this:

```
void Main()
{
    string name = "Jack";
}
```

Then you compiler optimised code is:

```
IL_0000:  ret
```

The compiler simply ignores the unused variable.

The unoptimised code generates this:

```
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldstr       "Jack"
IL_0006:  stloc.0     // name
IL_0007:  ret
```

Obviously the unoptimised code is more explanatory, so I'll only show unoptimsed code from now on unless I explicitly say otherwise.

Now let's make the code do something more interesting.

```
void Main()
{
    string name = "Jack";
    Console.WriteLine(name);
}
```

This produces:

```
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldstr       "Jack"
IL_0006:  stloc.0     // name
IL_0007:  ldloc.0     // name
IL_0008:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
IL_000D:  nop         
IL_000E:  ret
```

What's interesting is if we change this code to this:

```
void Main()
{
    int answer = 42;
    Console.WriteLine(answer);
}
```

We get this:

```
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.s    2A 
IL_0003:  stloc.0     // answer
IL_0004:  ldloc.0     // answer
IL_0005:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
IL_000A:  nop         
IL_000B:  ret
```

The code is virtually the same as the `string` example.

The `ldstr` call is getting a reference to a string literal (which is store in the String Pool on the Large Object Heap (not the normal heap which is the Small Object Heap) and pushing it on the evaluation stack.

The `ldc.i4.s` is pushing a reference to the number `42` on to the evaluation stack.

Then, in both cases, `stloc.0` is storing the value on top of the evaluation stack into the zeroth local memory location for the method.

Then, in both cases again, `ldloc.0` is loading the value from the zeroth local memory location and putting it on the evaluation stack.

You can probably imagine what the compiler might do if it were optimising this code.

Finally the `System.Console.WriteLine` is made.

Now let's look at that pesky `string` code in more detail.

I said that it's stored in the Intern Pool. Let's check that.

Take this code:

```
void Main()
{
    string name = "Jack";
    Console.WriteLine(String.IsInterned(name));
}
```

It produces:

```
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldstr       "Jack"
IL_0006:  stloc.0     // name
IL_0007:  ldloc.0     // name
IL_0008:  call        System.String.IsInterned
IL_000D:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
IL_0012:  nop         
IL_0013:  ret
```

And it outputs `Jack` to the console. It can only do that if `System.String.IsInterned` returns an interned string.

Take this program to show the opposite:

```
void Main()
{
    string name = String.Join("", new [] { "Ja", "ck" });
    Console.WriteLine(String.IsInterned(name));
}
```

It pushed out `null` to the console - meaning that the string `name` isn't interned so in this case `name` is stored on the heap (Small Object Heap).

Let's look at your second bit of code:

```
void Main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        Run();
    }
}

private void Run()
{
    int age = 20;
}
```

If we look at optimised IL then the `Run` method looks like this:

```
Run:
IL_0000:  ret
```

The unoptimised IL is this:

```
Run:
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.s    14 
IL_0003:  stloc.0     // age
IL_0004:  ret
```

And, like my earlier example with an `int`, it is loading the literal value `20` (or `14` in hex) onto the evaluation stack and then immediately storing it in the local memory for the method, and then returns. And hence it is repeating using the same memory 20 times for the local variable `age`.

Answer (score -1):

In your first example (uninitialized variable), it will not allocate any memory since it won't generate any MSIL. It will be the same as no code at all.
If you initialize it, memory will be allocated in the current method's stack.

Second case, the age variable will be allocated in the stack for each method call and should be released when each method call exits.

Comment: actually, in first example it will allocate - a variable on stack, one object reference, as soon as that method is invoked. It's small in size, but still it is an allocation, so it's not 'zero'.

Comment: Furthermore, interestingly enough, at `foo = "mom"`, "mom" is compile-time constant, and probably the "mom" string object will already exist as interned in string pool when this code is invoked, so no new objects will be created and just the reference will be written to the variable on stack, which was allocated previously, so few bytes copied, no allocation. If the line was something like `foo = new string(5, 'x')` or `foo = new List<int>` then it's a normal case and that would be allocate+construct+assign

Comment: ah yes. and as **Enigmativity** mentioned in another comment, there's also JIT and possibility that a variable will be put into register.. eh

Comment: @quetzalcoatl  Interesting, I tested on linqpad, with only the variable declaration, without initialization, it didn't generate any MSIL. Maybe linqpad is not a good reference for this.

Comment: sorry, I quietly assumed that we're talking about eager delcaration of variables that are used lower down in the code. Like `string foo; ...... foo = "mom";`. Stack variable will be allocated immediately upon method call, not at the point of assignement. In your case, with unused variable, the compiler simply optimized it out. It cannot be done for unused class members, but on the stack compiler can easily omit unused things.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl, to be honest, my answer was indeed ambiguous, I updated it to make it clearer. Thanks.