# how stack and heap work, memory storing (Duplicate)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

```
class Calculate
{
    int result;
    public int add(int m, int n)
    {
        result = m + n;
        return result;
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int a, b, c;
        a = 10;
        b = 20;
        Calculate obj;
        obj = new Calculate();
        c= obj.add(a, b);
        Console.WriteLine(c);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

this is a sample code, I wonder how stack and heap functions, and who variables,methods,class or objects
get stored, how stack is functioned line by line execution of code
and if 10 objects are create how and where these are stored

Comment: I found this [article](https://dev.to/tyrrrz/interview-question-heap-vs-stack-c-5aae) quite interesting. You need to understand the difference between reference type and value type. Then you can answer your question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Memory allocation: Stack vs Heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487289/memory-allocation-stack-vs-heap)

Answer (score 0):

**Heap**
All reference types (strings, objects) and static variable types are stored on the heap.

**Stack**
All value types are stored on the stack.

```
int result;
```

`result` will be on the heap too because it's a part of Calculate.

```
    int a, b, c;
    a = 10;
    b = 20;
```

`a, b, c` are all on the stack, because you give these variables a value on the main thread.

```
    Calculate obj;
```

`obj` will be on the heap, since it's a reference type.

For more information:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/value-types-and-reference-types

Comment: thanks for the info but what happens when only int a; is executed will memory gets allocated if it gets why compiler throws error when i write console.write(a); with out assigning

Comment: Int a has no value. On the stack you define space for a variable named a, but the value is empty. Are you still using C# 4? Last year C# 8 came out. I know that value types have a default value and shouldn't throw errors that way.

Comment: ohh! ok, thanks for that