# In Unity3D setting the Quaternion of a GameObject directly, without constructing a new object every time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, quaternions

I have a sensor that provides quaternions which I would like to apply to a GameObject.

My currently working code is the following:
`transform.rotation = new Quaternion(x, y, z, w);`
This works correctly, it modifies the rotation of the GameObject it's attached to, in the way it supposed to rotate it.

However the problem is that constructing a new object every frame seems very wasteful, so I would like to modify the existing one. I've tried the following code:
`transform.rotation.Set(x, y, z, w);`
This code simply doesn't modify the rotation of the GameObject at all.

Can I modify the Quaternion of the GameObject without constructing a new object every time?

Comment: Setting a Quaternion manually is folly at best.  To my knowledge, Unity's Quaternions are structs and so don't have the migrating-memory overheads that clases do (struct being a value-type meaning when you assign a 'new' one, it just copies the values over instead)

Comment: In terms of penalty for creating 'new' Quaternions, the amount of work you'd have to do to recreate the math for generating a Quaternion, IMHO, defeats the puprose.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, sorry for late reply! I'm not calculating the Quaternions, that's what the sensor gave me. I actually had problems converting to Euler, and that's why I switched to Quaternions, because then I just pass values, cannot screw them up. :) The answer I accepted works fine for that purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html) `Quaternion` is a struct, not a reference type.

This means:

- `transform.rotation` returns a copy of the current rotation of your object. Thus you cannot modify it by calling `transform.rotation.Set(x, y, z, w);`. You have to use an assignment call.
- You will not improve performance by caching the rotation in a member field, since the assignement will copy it anyway and your local Quaternion is allocated on the [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487289/memory-allocation-stack-vs-heap).

If you are afraid of performance (which you shouldn't be just because of the Quaternion construction), I would suggest you cache `transform` in a member, since Unity's `transform` member calls `this.gameObject.GetComponent<Transform>()` every time you use it, which is a rather expensive operation.
Though for true optimization we need to know your exact code.

Example:

```
public class MyClass
{
    // to be used instead of Unity's transform member
    private Transform myTransform;
    
    private void Awake()
    {
        // make expensive call only once during Awake
        myTransform = transform;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

From [API: Transform.rotation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-rotation.html)

> Do not attempt to edit/modify rotation.

I suspect this is because the `rotation` is used purely as a convenience, and the actual transformation matrix is only updated during a function or property-set call.  Modifying the `rotation` directly thus doesn't trigger the matrix update.

You could try modifying the rotation and then calling `rotate(0,0,0)`, but no guarantees this will work as `rotation` may not be the 'ground-truth', it may not even be stored. It may be generated on request from the matrix.